# windows7 computer blue screens everytime its on. Hardware or OS damage?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

My computer restarts everytime I turn it on, It blue screens after the welcome display. I was thinking if the thermal gel for the fan melted or anything inside was broken because I dont use external fan or is it a virus? OS damage? how can I fix it without losing my data?

Comment: Basic diagnostics 101: Boot from a liveCD (or a pendrive version of that). If that does not crash it is probably a software problem. If the crashes remain is is probably hardware.

Comment: What is the STOP code (STOP 0x.......)? That will tell us more about it. A good portion of frequently seen STOP codes point to memory. So a run of Memtest x86 is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

BSOD most likely not your computer its self but rather software that is damaged especially if your hard-drive is old and has bad sectors..

Answer (score 0):

I think a good place to start with is a drive test, *assuming this drive is a spinning disk and not an SSD*. There are a variety of bootable disk utilities to test the health of Hard Drives. One simple but effective tool I like to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/index-files/simpletech-legacy-downloads#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.

If DFT reports that the drive is failing (diagnostics in red box) you should check to see if the drive is still under warranty and if possible file an RMA claim to get it replaced.  If it does not report any problems (green ok) then you don't need to worry for the time being about Hard Drive health and should look elsewhere for the problem.

Another good thing to test for would be faulty RAM, with something like [Memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/)+.

If both those tests pass then there is a good chance that your hardware is okay and a good next step would be to start troubleshooting the BSOD errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to copy your date first and do whatever you want. Take your hard drive out and plug it to different computer then copy everything.

Answer (score 0):

boot the computer, and let it crash and reboot
start pressing F8 about 1 time a second until you get a menu
look for and select "Disable Automatic Restart"
Start Windows
Get a blue crash screen or BSOD or Blue Screen of Death
Look for a STOP code and report it here or google it.

If it is the hard drive:
boot from "windows install disc"
select   repair 
command prompt

chkdsk /R c:

Wait for it to finish, possibly several hours

Reboot and see what happens.